# Input redirection from file gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I can't get gdb to redirect a file to the stdin of my program.

Outside of gdb `./prog.x < someinput.txt` does exactly what I want.

Inside gdb, when I run `(gdb) run < someinput.txt` my program doesn't seem to "see" the input file, and instead stdin seems to be reading what I type into the console.

```
(gdb) run < testinput.txt
Starting program: /Users/alexpatch/Documents/krc/misc/sandbox.x < testinput.txt
[New Thread 0x1603 of process 8308]
```

My cursor appears on a blank line beneath that, where I can type some text. C-d breaks out of that, then the output of the program run with what I just typed appears, and the process exits normally.

```
/* trivial code example */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);

  return 0;
}
```

I found a few answers related to similar issues, but the solution that seemed to work for them was what I'm already doing, namely `(gdb) run < someinput.txt`. In case it's helpful, I'm working on a 64bit MacBook Air running macOS Sierra.

Comment: By the way, `EOF` does not fit in a `char`, which is why `getchar()` returns `int`.

Comment: @unwind thank you. I didn't know that-- genuinely appreciate the tip.

Comment: Also, answering a question posed by someone who has since deleted their response, I'm using gdb v7.12.1, which as of this writing is the latest stable release.

Comment: Huh, this is weird. Have you tried something like `run $(cat testinput.txt)` (using command substitution)?

Comment: @BenSteffan Just tried that-- same result. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexPatch Okay, that is really weird. Could you please tell us the version of gdb you are using?

Comment: @BenSteffan gdb v7.12.1 on macOS sierra

Comment: Could you run `gdb cat` and then try the same `run < testinput.txt` command?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick running `gdb cat` causes the program to terminate with signal ?, Unknown signal. This happens regardless of whether I direct testinput.txt to run.