# GDB input redirection not working on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.3

Tags: redirect, input, gdb, macos-high-sierra

I'm using GDB 8.0.1 on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.3. Basically, doing:

```
(gdb) r < some_input_file.in
```

ignores the input file. It acts as if the command ran was simply

```
(gdb) r
```

The closest thread I found about this problem was [Input redirection from file gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206373/input-redirection-from-file-gdb?newreg=1e79e72449d349ebb46394a9b4b54d39) but no solution was posted.

Any clues?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into an interaction between gdb and macOS SIP ("System Integrity Protection").

gdb implements `run` redirections by passing the command line to the shell; then it waits for the shell to invoke your program before starting to "really debug".  The shell is actually still controlled by gdb using `ptrace` -- gdb uses this to observe the eventual exec and to ensure that your process is also traced.

However, SIP prevents certain programs from being traced, and in particular programs in `/usr/bin`, like most shells.  This causes `run` to stop working entirely, because the shell can't be started.

So, to make gdb continue to work, users often `set startup-with-shell off`.  Perhaps whatever gdb build you are using does this by default (or maybe, like me, you put this in your `.gdbinit` and forgot about it).  This setting lets `run` work -- but at the cost of disabling redirections.

There's a [gdb bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23364) for this which you can follow.

Comment: This bug is marked as fixed, but as far as I can tell, gdb input redirection does not work on gdb on MacOS Catalina as of now.

Comment: You have to be sure to use the correct version of gdb.  However, I think gdb isn't working on Catalina at all - there's no active macOS gdb maintainer, and there was some change to the system that made gdb stop working.

Comment: Oh, I got gdb to work fine on Catalina just from a standard ```brew install``` - it's just that the redirection doesn't work. In order to make it work though you need to code sign the binary, which is a bit of a hassle.

I mostly followed these instructions: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin

But I would have to agree that using gdb under catalina (and macos in general) might be more hassle than it's worth.