# GDB Input Redirection not working on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: c, macos, gdb, macos-big-sur

I am using macOS Big Sur, v11.5.2, and GDB v10.2

I have seen similar issues before, but with no clear answer.
I am trying to run a program in GDB with input redirection

```
sudo gdb ./executable
r < input.txt
```

But when I do this the shell hangs, waiting for manual input instead of reading input from the file. I have gone through the process of creating code signing certificate for GDB, running as sudo, but the same issue occurs.

I also know about MacOS's SIP and how that interferes. [This link](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23364), coming from this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51492932/gdb-input-redirection-not-working-on-mac-os-high-sierra-10-13-3) doesn't seem to offer any solutions. At least any solution that maintains the ability to use input/output redirection in GDB.

If anyone has an answer and can clearly articulate it here, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have `set startup-with-shell off` in your GDB init file? That's sometimes recommended on MacOS systems. If that's set, then no shell will be used, and `"<"` and `"input.txt"` will simply be passed as arguments to the program.

Comment: I do not have that in my init file. Although that is not what I am looking for. I don't want "<" and "input.txt" to be passed as arguments. I want the contents of input.txt to be passed to stdin via input redirection. This works on windows and linux machines.

Comment: OK, I'm just trying to eliminate that as a possibility. In GDB, can you type `start` and then `print argv` , just to see what arguments your program is getting?

Comment: I have just opted to use `lldb` instead of `gdb`, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* This isn't so much a complete solution as some workarounds and suggestions [that are too big to fit into a comment].

There's basically *two* issues:

1. Does gdb's `r` command [under macOS] allow input redirection?
2. Can `gdb` be run under `sudo`?

So, let's start by eliminating `sudo`. Does the following work:

```
gdb ./executable
r < input.txt
```

If not, either the `run` command's input redirection does *not* work *or* there is a bug in the executable.

*Side note:* For many years, I did *not* know that `run` *could* take I/O redirection [silly me :-)].

What I usually do/did is modify the program to allow input either from `stdin` *or* from an argument [just like `cat`]. Then, I'd do:

```
gdb ./executable
set args input.txt
run
```

The other issue is whether `gdb` can be run under `sudo`.

In the past, I've tried to debug a `setuid` executable as an ordinary user [if possible]. This eliminates the complexity of trying to run `gdb` and the executable as `root`. Sometimes this involves creating a test directory that mirrors/mimics the necessary file hierarchy [but the files are owned by the non-root user] and using (e.g.) `chroot` or equivalent

Much of the debug can be done this way without root privileges. For the parts that *do* require root, I often resort to `printf` debug messages--YMMV.

I'm *not* familiar with macOS, so I don't know how [the aformentioned] `SIP` will respond to the following ...

Another trick I've used is to make the executable [and a *copy* of `gdb`] into `setuid` programs:

```
cp /usr/bin/gdb /home/me/mygdb
sudo chown root /home/me/mygdb
sudo chmod 6741 /home/me/mygdb
sudo chown root /home/me/myprogram
sudo chmod 6741 /home/me/myprogram
```

Then, I run the modified programs. This can bypass some of the issues with using `sudo` directly on the target programs.

Of course, I try to make sure that there is *no* access to the containing directory by others. And, I remove the files when done testing.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response.
1. There is no issue with the syntax, and is an accepted command.
2. Yes it can be run under sudo, when I don't run it under sudo I get a code signing error, even though I've made the code signing certificate. This error goes away when running as sudo.

Unfortunately with your trick of making a copy of gdb did not work :/

I don't understand why apple has to make this so difficult. gdb works fine on my windows and linux machines (with input redirection).